# How does one store the "original capture date" metadata item for a QuickTime movie?

Tags: quicktime

Quicktime has a rich metadata API, allowing one to store all sorts of arbitrary data on a .mov file (or one of its streams).  I'm looking for the standard key name and value format for storing the shooting date for a video clip, analogous to EXIF's DateTimeOriginal.

The following discussion at the apple site makes it seem like there may not be one defined by apple, as they don't seem to feel it's very important. 
http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=6267622

This is related to [How can I get the original capture timestamp from my home movie files:: AVI and MPG4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213015/) (which deals with .mp4 and .avi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no standard key for this kind of metadata.
You might try to use a reasonably fitting standard key like

kQTMetaDataCommonKeyInformation,

kQTMetaDataCommonKeyDescription or

kQTMetaDataCommonKeyProducer

although this wouldn't be 'standard' (i.e. would most likely only be processed correctly by your application).

On the question which value format to use this sample code and Q&A article (although it is not exactly fitting) might set you on the right track:

http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2007/qa1515.html
http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/QTMetaData/listing1.html